# libvirtd: No more available PCI slots

Tags: fedora, hard-disk, virtual-machine, kvm, pci

Ahoy.
Today I wanted to set up a new virtual machine to manage my 8 hard disk devices.

Currently I use Fedora 31 as host, and Debian 9 as guest system.
I want to pass through the block devices to the virtual machine, but unfortunately it doesn't work, and it's quite hard to find proper information without being a RedHat subscriber.

So what did I do? I try to attach the hard disk using, the following command.

```
virsh attach-disk Storage_ZFS_\(Debian\) /dev/sdb vdc
```

Unfortunately I receive the following error.

```
error: Failed to attach disk
error: internal error: No more available PCI slots
```

So what did I try? I did some research, and found something what has worked on SUSE, adding `<controller type='pci' model='pcie-to-pci-bridge'/>` somewhere in the VM's  section, but unfortunately it didn't work as well.
Only received the following error.

```
[root@millenium-fbe48 chairman]# virsh edit Storage_ZFS_\(Debian\) 
error: internal error: Cannot automatically add a new PCI bus for a device with connect flags 800
Failed. Try again? [y,n,i,f,?]: 
error: XML error: The PCI controller with index='0' must be model='pcie-root' for this machine type, but model='pcie-to-pci-bridge' was found instead
Failed. Try again? [y,n,i,f,?]: 
error: XML error: The PCI controller with index='0' must be model='pcie-root' for this machine type, but model='pcie-to-pci-bridge' was found instead
Failed. Try again? [y,n,i,f,?]: 
error: XML error: The PCI controller with index='0' must be model='pcie-root' for this machine type, but model='pcie-to-pci-bridge' was found instead
Failed. Try again? [y,n,i,f,?]: 
error: XML error: The PCI controller with index='0' must be model='pcie-root' for this machine type, but model='pcie-to-pci-bridge' was found instead
Failed. Try again? [y,n,i,f,?]: 
error: XML error: The PCI controller with index='0' must be model='pcie-root' for this machine type, but model='pcie-to-pci-bridge' was found instead
Failed. Try again? [y,n,i,f,?]:
```

Does someone knows how to deal with it, and how to add the hard disks to my guest VM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to add multiple PCI passthrough device using the following approach.

If you do the attach-interface command with `--config` *only* (remove the
`--live`), libvirt will be able to automatically add the pcie-root-port
that it knows is required. Then you'll just need to shutdown and restart
the guest for the device to be added to the running guest instance (a
simple reboot from the guest is insufficient, you need to fully shut it
down, so that a new qemu process is started)

So basically .

1. `virsh attach-device VM_NAME PCI_entry.xml --config`
2. `virsh destroy VM_NAME`
3. `virsh start VM_NAME`

Source: [Re: [libvirt-users] unable to add pci network to existing vm](https://www.redhat.com/archives/libvirt-users/2018-December/msg00043.html)

Comment: Thanks!!! Has worked for me

Answer (score 3):

The problem has been solved.
There is a way to solve this problem by adding PCI/PCIe bridges, but it seems to be quite complicated, and there is a lack of information.
So i found a libvirt documentation page provided by RedHat, having a load of information.
To sum up: There are 3 ways to add block devices to the guest VM, i used an easy one.
Simply editing the xml file of the desired target, by using `virsh edit "domain"`, and adding the following content bellow the last  statement, appearing in the file.

```
<disk type='block' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none'/>
      <source dev='/dev/sdx'/>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
</disk>
```

In order to get it work you still have to replace "vda" and "sdx" in your case.
Using this method, PCI bridges will be created automatically. Very easy to solve this problem using this way.

Link to the article. [13.3.2. Adding Hard Drives and Other Block Devices to a Guest](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/virtualization_administration_guide/sect-virtualization-adding_storage_devices_to_guests-adding_hard_drives_and_other_block_devices_to_a_guest)

Answer (score 1):

Use --live while machine is working do not use it if its offline

to create some test disks in bash :

```
for i in {1..12};do sudo qemu-img create -f raw testdisk$i.raw 10G;done
```

to attach disks in python3:

```
import os
y='g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,r,s,t,u,v,y,z'.split(',')
for i in range(1,13):
    s='virsh attach-disk optmb_fileserver '+'/home/gediz/Desktop/testdisk'+str(i)+'.raw '+'vd'+y[i]+' --config --live'
    print(os.popen(s).read())
```

Answer (score 0):

Shut down your VM, then use `--persistent`:

```bash
virsh attach-disk GuestVM /dev/sda1 vda --persistent
```